# Casting a (ptr to const ) to (ptr to uint8)

Tags: c, embedded

Is there a way in "C" to cast a (ptr to const structure ) to (ptr to uint8)

the following function expects (ptr to uint8)

```
memcopy( (uint8 *) destination, (uint8 *) source , uint16 _size);
```

The function intends to copy the buffer of type ((ptr to const)) to another buffer

i'm aware in C++ i may use const_cast to cast away (remove) constness or volatility. but how about C ?

the current case is as follow:
say i have a structure main_S

```
struct main_S {
strcut1 xxxx1
strcut2 xxxx2
strcut3 xxxx3
}
```

the pointer to the main_S strcut is (ptrcnst_Main) and it's a pointer to const.

i need to copy the 2nd element (xxxx2) of the main_S 
so i'll do the following

```
strcut2 dest;
memcopy( (uint8 *) &destination, (uint8 *) ptrcnst_Main->xxxx2 , SizeOf(strcut2));
```

But this never works. and i keep having error that i cant cast ptr const to ptr-uint8

Comment: Why can't  the function argument `source` be `const`, similar to the library function `void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)`?

Comment: Well i forgot to mention that the (ptr to const) is (ptr to const structure type) and i have to cast it to uint8  to use it with the memcopy function , @WeatherVane

Comment: Do you mean `memcpy` rather than `memcopy`?

Comment: You need to be more clear about whether `source` or `destination` or both start out as "ptr to const structure".

Comment: the source starts as ptr to const structure were as the destination is just regular ptr to struct which can be casted to uint8 with no complains  @user3386109

Comment: @KeithThompson well it's a function i have implemented which copy byte by byte from the source to the destination. my main goal is to copy a struct to another by using a ptr to the source structure

Comment: I hope you're aware that there's a function in the standard C library, `memcpy`, that does the same thing. It's hard to tell whether `memcopy` is your own function or a typo for the standard one (and BTW identifiers starting with `mem` are reserved to the implementation). I suggest giving it a different name -- or just using the standard `memcpy` if it's available. And what is `SizeOf`? Also, please include the error message in the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson thank you for your comment , i dont think im using standard C libraries at my project , im developing for an embedded controller, i m aware of the  memcopy thats why i was trying  to mimic it's behavior, and i stumbled by  that issue.

Comment: So is `main_S->xxxx2` a pointer to a struct, or just a struct. In other words, why isn't it `&main_S->xxxx2`?

Comment: @user3386109 sorry it shall be ptrcnst_Main->xxxx2 , i've fixed it

Comment: Yes, `Main` is a pointer, but that still doesn't make `Main->xxxx2` a pointer.

Comment: Ok.  So what is `SizeOf`? Did you copy-and-paste your *exact* code into the question? If not, typos can make it very difficult to figure out what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I just read your comments, it's getting strange... The code is very approximative but i'll try to solve your problem.

```
strcut2 dest;
memcopy( (uint8 *)&dest, (uint8 *)&(ptrcnst_Main->xxxx2) , SizeOf(strcut2));
```

Try to add an ampersand (&) in front of your `ptrcnst_Main->xxxx2` and put parantheses just like I did.

---

Usually, when you are copying data from a buffer to another without applying any changes to the source buffer, you declare your variable as a constant pointer because **it won't change**! It's a *source* buffer. So here, your pointer `source` should be `const uint8 *source`. Even if it's a constant pointer, you will be able to read the value inside.

Put `const` qualifier on non-mutable data (read "data which doesn't need to change"), is a good practice for you and every of your colleagues.

**Conclusion**
You don't need to cast anything from `const` to non-`const`. Constant variable still can be read.

**However**, I will answer your original question which is :

> Is there a way in "C" to cast a (ptr to const) to (ptr to uint8)?

In C, you simply cast as follow: `(type) variable`

For example :

```
const char* c1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
char* c2 = (char*)c1; // cast is here
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
   c2[i] = 'i';
}
printf("%s\n", c1);
```

But it's a very bad practice to remove constness. If it's constant, it's usually on purpose.

**Note :** That code is bad on a lots of point, but i kept it simple for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Most likely he has to cast away the const because his home-brewed memcopy() got a bad function prototype without proper const-correctness. So the actual problem is the function declaration of memcopy.

Comment: Just as I suspected it. Thanks for enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

For C, you use a regular C-style cast to cast away constness.  For example:

```
void f(const int *src,int *dst,int n)
{
    memcopy((uint8_t*)dst,(uint8_t*)src,n*sizeof(int));
}
```

Note that actually writing to an object that was originally declared const is undefined behavior, so be careful.